# Timeit not returning actual time

Tags: python-3.x, time, timeit

I am testing an implementation of Heap using the `timeit` module, but I can't get it to print time in float:

```
def testCustomHeapStartUp(*args):
    h = MinHeap(args[0])
    return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(3):
        testList = random.sample(range(100), 100)
        print(timeit.Timer("testCustomHeapStartUp(testList)", \
            "from __main__ import testCustomHeapStartUp; from __main__ import testList; gc.enabled()"))
```

This is the output:

```
<timeit.Timer object at 0x101a58978>
<timeit.Timer object at 0x101a58978>
<timeit.Timer object at 0x101a58978>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`timeit.Timer(...)` only creates the instance, it doesn't run and time the code.

You need to call the `.timeit()` function on the `Timer` instance:

```
print(timeit.Timer(..., ...).timeit(n))
```

Where `n` is the number of times you want `timeit()` to to run the snippet.

Because `timeit` is showing up so often, I would refactor your code as:

```
from timeit import Timer

def testCustomHeapStartUp(*args):
    h = MinHeap(args[0])
    return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(3):
        testList = random.sample(range(100), 100)
        t = Timer(
            "testCustomHeapStartUp(testList)",
            "from __main__ import testCustomHeapStartUp; from __main__ import testList; gc.enabled()",
            )
        print(t.timeit())
```